# Reducing the time complexity of stair-step question (Amazon interview question)

Tags: python, recursion

```
def step(n):
    if (n==0) or (n==1):
        return 1 
    elif n==2:
        return 2
    else:
        return step(n-1) + step(n-2) + step(n-3)
n = int(input())
print(step(n))
```

For input 53798080 it is taking 1 second. It should take a lot lesser than that to satisfy the test case.

Comment: Sounds like a math problem more than anything. Also throws a stack overflow with `step(-1)` or any floating point number.

Comment: No float inputs to be given.

Comment: Probably start by noticing that you compute the same step multiple times.

Comment: is it okay if you point them out for me?

Comment: For example `n=5`, you will do: `step(4) + step(3) + step(2)` which in turn is `(step(3) + step(2) + step(1)) + ( step(2) + step(1) + step(0) ) + 2`, then `(( step(2) + step(1) + step(0) ) + 2 + 1) + ( 2 + 1 + 1 ) + 2` and so on. The smaler n, the more times its re-computed.

Comment: I know right. The question was supposed to be solved using the recursion approach and not the other way around.

Comment: Functional languages often speed-up pure functions by caching their results. You can do that. I solved this with a single loop ( therefore O(N) ), but you can't do that using recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of problem - evaluating a recurrence relation - has had a lot of smart people study it over the years, and that means that there's a ton of cool insights and ideas you can use to speed things up.

The comments have done a great job identifying why your code slows down on large inputs - it's because you're generating lots of duplicate recursive calls. The question, then, is how to address this.

If you want to keep your same basic strategy, I would recommend using [***memoization***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). If you haven't seen this technique before, the basic idea is to have the recursion keep track of calls that have already been made and to cache the results of those calls. Then, if you try solving the same problem twice, you can just hand back the cached result.

The general template for memoization looks something like this. (It's in pseudocode, but shouldn't be too hard to adapt.)

```
def memoized_recursion(original_args, memoization_table):
    if memoization_table contains original_args):
        return memoization_table[original_args]
    else
        # Put the rest of your recursive code here.
        # Before returning a result, store it in memoization_table.
```

This reduces the number of recursive calls pretty dramatically, speeding up your code.

This, of course, isn't the only solution to making your code faster. If you have to keep things recursive, there's a different insight you can use that fundamentally changes the strategy. The basic idea is this. You're generating a series of numbers that looks like this:

```
1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, ...
```

The idea is that

- the first three terms are 1, 1, 2;
- every term past this one is the sum of the three previous numbers; and
- you want the nth term of the series.

If you need terms 0, 1, or 2, you can just read the answer off because you know the first three numbers.

If not, here's another technique you can use. Rather than getting the three previous values and adding them together, use this useful fact: asking for the nth term of the series starting with 1, 1, 2 is equivalent to asking for the (n-1)st term of the series starting with 1, 2, 4. (Do you see why?)

More generally, if the first three terms of the series are a, b, and c and you want the nth term, you can ask for the (n-1)st term of the series starting with the sequence b, c, a + b + c. This gives a different recursive strategy where the recursion doesn't branch, meaning that you don't need memoization.

And now, one final strategy. The type of problem you're solving involves something called a ***homogeneous linear recurrence relation***. That is, you have a recurrence of the form

- a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, ..., and a<sub>k-1</sub> are fixed constants, and
- a<sub>n+k</sub> = c<sub>0</sub> a<sub>n</sub> + c<sub>1</sub> a<sub>n+1</sub> + ... + c<sub>k-1</sub>a<sub>n+k-1</sub>.

This recurrence includes things like the Fibonacci sequence, the Pell numbers, the Padovan sequence, etc.

It turns out that in any case where you're solving a recurrence like this, you can solve the problem by raising specifically-chosen matrices to specific powers. In your case, the basic idea is related to the one for the second recursive strategy. The idea is that if the last three terms of the sequence are a, b, and c, then you know that the the next term is a + b + c, and the two terms before this are b and c. In other words, you can think of a mapping that turns (a, b, c) into (b, c, a + b + c). This can be thought of as this matrix equation:

```
| 0  1  0 | |a|   |     b     |
| 0  0  1 | |b| = |     c     |
| 1  1  1 | |c|   | a + b + c |
```

If you let M be the matrix on the far left, then computing Mn and multiplying it by the column vector (a, b, c) will give you the nth, (n+1)st, and (n+2)nd terms of the recurrence relation. This gives a totally different strategy for solving the problem: build a matrix, then raise it to a large power!

You can do this very efficiently, in fact. There's a (recursive) technique called [***exponentiation by squaring***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) that can compute the nth power of a matrix using only O(log n) multiplications. (The entries of the matrix will start to get pretty big, and multiplying them will start to be your bottleneck, unfortunately). It might be worth checking out this strategy, though, since it's a pretty cool technique!

And, finally, one last option. If you do some Googling, you'll find that your problem is closely related to finding the nth [***tribonacci number***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Tribonacci_numbers). There are some cool formulas you can use to compute this directly, also involving powers of numbers, though they might introduce some rounding errors that slow things down a bit too much for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

> For input 53798080 it is taking 1 second.

I highly doubt this.  Your code stack overflows on this input.  What I believe is going on here is that it takes 1 second for input *30* to produce the *output* 53798080.  By input 31, we're up to nearly *half a minute*.

If we memoize your code:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
def step(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1

    if n == 2:
        return 2

    return step(n-1) + step(n-2) + step(n-3)
```

It fixes the speed problem, as @templatetypedef explains.  But, it blows up with stack overflow (assuming you don't allocate more stack) above input 500.  We can double that range, and deal with the speed problem sans memoization, using a more efficient algorithm with fewer recursions:

```
def step(n, prev1=2, prev2=1, prev3=1):
    if 0 <= n <= 1:
        return 1

    if n == 2:
        return prev1

    return step(n - 1, prev3 + prev2 + prev1, prev1, prev2)
```

This will handle input up to 999 and produce a result in a fraction of a second:

```
> time python3 test.py
1499952522327196729941271196334368245775697491582778125787566254148069690528296568742385996324542810615783529390195412125034236407070760756549390960727215226685972723347839892057807887049540341540394345570010550821354375819311674972209464069786275283520364029575324
0.032u 0.011s 0:00.04 100.0%    0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
>
```

(Adding `@lru_cache` to this code will reduce the input range back to the original and make no difference speed-wise.)